# Need to retrieve binary file from server and display it as pdf using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fileapi

This is the code I am referring to:

```
var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
var content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
$window.open(content);
```

I am also passing responseType:'arraybuffer' as a second parameter while making a GET request. But I am getting 'Failed to load PDF document' in the new window and blob:null.

Comment: could you try to do it just window.open(content) ?  (without $widnow)

Comment: I just tried your solution. I am getting the same issue 'Failed to upload PDF' even with window.open

Comment: so it's nothing to do with Angular

Comment: The issue seems to be with parameters being sent with http get request. I am using this code:

 $http.get('/myURL',{ responseType:'arraybuffer'});

There might be some parameter needed.Why the binary contents are not getting decoded correctly  I am not able to figure out. The content of the document is not getting loaded and blob is giving null.